# Trouble accessing app.flutterflow.io after clearing Chrome cache - Err_connection_reset

Tags: windows, google-chrome, flutterflow

Description of the issue:

I recently cleared my Chrome cache, and now I'm experiencing problems accessing app.flutterflow.io. The site only displays the splash image, accompanied by the following errors in the console:

net::Err_connection_reset 200 (OK)
Uncaught (in promise)...

1. Cleared Chrome cache.
2. Attempted to refresh the page.
3. Checked internet connection.

Expected behavior:

The site should load properly after clearing the cache.

Any insights or suggestions on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: It shows Failed to load resource: net::ERR_QUIC_PROTOCOL_ERROR and Uncaught (in promise) error from the console. I tried disabling chrome quick experimental protocol and relaunch but still did not open app.flutterflow.io/project...